# primefaces editable datable with autocomplete stuck up on edit or edit cancel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have an editable primefaces datatable with two (2) autocomplete fields. I use lazy loading to load up to 50 rows. When user displays all rows(350 at most), row edit or cancel edit gets stuck. I get a warning:

> GRIZZLY0173: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([10,000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.

Commenting out autocomplete seems to solve the problem but I need it somehow. Any suggestions or ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: Start reading about PrimeFaces partial-submit

Comment: cool thanks bud! ill try it